# what is main action in clang::PluginASTAction::ActionType

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I am having some confusion regarding clang frontend API `ActionType` while working on a project which is building a clang plugin.

When an action is to be executed can be changed by overriding `clang::PluginASTAction::getActionType` virtual function, this function returns value of type `ActionType`

ActionType enum in clang is defined as

```
enum ActionType {
     Cmdline,             ///< Action is determined by the cc1 command-line
     ReplaceAction,       ///< Replace the main action
     AddBeforeMainAction, ///< Execute the action before the main action
     AddAfterMainAction   ///< Execute the action after the main action
   };
```

What is `main action` here ? How will the action performed by plugin will be impacted if I change from `AddBeforeMainAction` to `AddAfterMainAction` ?